# Getting null in HttpSessionStateBase c# unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, httprequest, httpsession

While running my unit test method, I am getting null values in instance of HttpSessionStateBase. I have mocked the httpcontext like this

```
var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/", "");
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer("id", 
                                                     new SessionStateItemCollection(),
                                                     new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(), 
                                                     10, 
                                                     true,
                                                     HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
                                                     SessionStateMode.InProc, 
                                                     false);

SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(httpContext, sessionContainer);
```

Please suggest some ideas to get some dummy values in HttpSessionStateBase

Comment: What's `SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext` and where exactly are you getting null values? Please show how are you trying to access the Session object in the actual code that you are trying to unit test.

Comment: public ActionResult Login(Customer obj) { Session.Clear(); }, This Session is in the type of HttpSessionStateBase

Comment: var result = (RedirectToRouteResult)controller.Login(new Customer() {  AdminLogin = "admin", Password = "admin" });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's suppose that you have the following controller action that you need to unit test:

```
public class AccountController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login(Customer obj)
    {
        Session.Clear();
        return View();
    }
}
```

and here's a sample wire-up:

```
// arrange
var httpRequest = new HttpRequest("", "http://localhost/", "");
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(stringWriter);
var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
var sessionContainer = new HttpSessionStateContainer(
    "id",
    new SessionStateItemCollection(),
    new HttpStaticObjectsCollection(),
    10,
    true,
    HttpCookieMode.AutoDetect,
    SessionStateMode.InProc,
    false);
SessionStateUtility.AddHttpSessionStateToContext(httpContext, sessionContainer);

var controller = new AccountController();
var requestContext = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), new RouteData());
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, controller);

// act
var actual = controller.Login(new Customer());

// assert
...
```

Notice that you need to populate the `controller.ControllerContext` property before calling the actions.

Comment: Great help. Thank you vary much

Comment: I am getting error in this line. FormsAuthentication.SignOut()

Comment: `FormsAuthentication.SignOut` internally depends on the static `HttpContext.Current` property. For obvious reasons this cannot be unit tested outside of an ASP.NET application. I would recommend you abstracting such hardcoded dependencies behind a facade of yours and then work with your facade in the controller. This would allow you to easily unit test your controllers in isolation of any ASP.NET specific contexts.